# Installation of Java on Debian 6

Tags: debian, java

To install java on debian 6, I used

```
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

The installation finished without any errors. But when I test the current version (java --version), I still get 1.5.0, and not 1.6.x?! Where is the mistake? Do I have to perform some other steps to install Java 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian and Debian-based systems usually /usr/bin/java is just a symlink to /etc/alternatives/java. The reason for this design is that many versions of the same software can coexist together (in your case Java 1.5 and 1.6).

Run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

to choose default Java version.

For further information on updates-alternatives see:

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/91